# Returning an array in c++ conversion function

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, return-type, function-definition, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to learn c++ with OpenGL. OpenGL renders on a coordinate system from -1 to 1 on the x and y axis. I am trying to make a function to convert pixels to openGL coordinates. I have this code:

```cpp
float pixelsToCoordinates(int pixels[2]) {
    float r[2] = { (pixels[0] - windowWidth / 2) / (windowWidth / 2) * windowWidth / windowHeight, (pixels[1] - windowHeight / 2) / (windowHeight / 2) };
    return r;
}
```

I get this error on `cpp return r;`:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0120   return value type does not match the function type  OpenGL-Engine

I think it has something to do with how arrays work in c++. What is th issue here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to return an array, your return type must be an array, not `float`.

Comment: Do some research about [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). If allowed, compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Comment: You cannot return an array from a C++ function (unless it's an `std::array`),

Comment: Please provide some [mre] - C++ code with `main`, and explicit compilation command - in your next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th expression in the return type

```
return r;
```

has the type `float *` due to the implicit conversion of an array designator to a pointer to its first element.

On the other hand. the return type of the function is `float`.

So the compiler issues an error message because there is no implicit conversion from the pointer type `float *` to the type `float`.

But if you will, change the return type of the function from `float` to `float *` there will be another problem of returning a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function

As your array contains only two elements then you could return an object of the type `std::pair<float, float>` instead of trying to return an array.

For example

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::pair<float, float> pixelsToCoordinates( const int pixels[] ) {
    return { (pixels[0] - windowWidth / 2.0f) / (windowWidth / 2.0f) * windowWidth / windowHeight, (pixels[1] - windowHeight / 2.0f) / (windowHeight / 2.0f) };
}
```

Another alternative is to return an object of the type `std::array<float, 2>`.

```
#include <array>

//...

std::array<float, 2> pixelsToCoordinates( const int pixels[] ) {
    return { (pixels[0] - windowWidth / 2.0f) / (windowWidth / 2.0f) * windowWidth / windowHeight, (pixels[1] - windowHeight / 2.0f) / (windowHeight / 2.0f) };
}
```

And one more alternative is to define the destination array in the caller of the function and pass it as an argument to the function. For example

```
float ( & pixelsToCoordinates( const int pixels[], float ( &a )[2] ) )[2];
```

Pay attention to that if you want to get values of the type float then in general you should use expressions of the type float used as initializers.

Comment: It's all fine but OpenGL API won't like `std::pair<float, float>` much.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. You can reassign the returned object to an array or something else. There is no problem.

Comment: You can, but why multiply entities beyond necessity? `std::array::data()` can be sent to OpenGL directly so this should be the preferred alternative.